# Deck Gate design for offset posts

Tags: deck, gates

I’m trying to build a deck gate at top of stairs.  Problem is I have to offset 6x6 posts.

What should I do, Should I just add another 6x6 post in the nearest post to make it even?

[image]

Comment: Think adding a second post will look like a patch job.  Would make gate longer than opening and use the post as a stop point/surface.  From picture post outside edge is inline with other post inside edge.  It also depends which post will have the hinges and way gate opens.

Comment: The gate latch will stick out from the post.  Maybe it will be enough to make it look OK.  The gate could also extend past the near post making it look OK.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you are over thinking the need to have the gate be somehow "even". You should just hinge the gate at the post that is on the side nearest the street. Then just simply arrange the gate to swing up against the deck side of the closer post. The diagram below shows how it is done. The typical hinge usage for this type of application is also shown.

[image]

As you can see from the above diagram the gate ends up being "even" (parallel) with the deck boards.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with a previous response that adding a second post will look like a patch job.

Depending on the run length and the size of the concrete foundation you may be able to move one of the posts relatively easily by replacing the rails and cap. The post would be off-center on the concrete foundation but that's a lot less visible than the issue you have.

Depending on the space you could also make a feature of it and build a small table  / planter. Think a four sided box with the post being the corner. If you do go for the planter idea get fit a plastic box and ensure you have some sort of drainage into a pile that goes below the deck.

[image]